# VPN Troubleshooting

Tags: vpn

I'm having continuing trouble with a SonicWall VPN. Does anyone know where I can get a trouble-shooting protocol that can help me find the problem?

Comment: Please be more specific when you ask questions.

Comment: What kind of trouble?  Are you getting error messages?  What's working and what isn't?  Please describe the symptoms of the problem, and there would be less chance of the question getting closed.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried SonicWall support?

Comment: e;fb.  Support is the way to go when you have no idea what is going on which is typically the case when no detail is provided.

Comment: Sonicwall is a great place, as mentioned. However, they will likely want a bit more detail as well if they are going to assist with the issue

Comment: Yeah, but at least they're paid to pull teeth.

Answer (score 2):

To troubleshoot VPN issues use the following steps:

1. Login to the web management interface
2. Go to Log -> Categories
3. Under each of the VPN categories (VPN, VPN Client, VPN IKE, VPN IPSEC, VPN PKI)
4. Disable your VPN connection
5. Enable your VPN connection
6. Go to Log -> View and watch for error messages.

After getting your error messages, go to: [Sonicwall's Knowledge base](http://support.sonicwall.com/us/support/kb.asp) and enter in the error message in the search string.  Usually the error messages are in all capitals, like: NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN.

In my experience, most of the problems come down to the setup of the VPN parameters not matching up between each end of the tunnel.  Specifically the ID used for the local and peer IKE IDs.  It is our practice to always use the **SonicWALL Identifier** as this is the most reliable.

Good luck